# Moving an unanswered question from MathOverflow

Tags: support, migration, mathoverflow, cross-posting

If I have a question unanswered in the MathOverflow for over three days, can I post it here to attract more attention? 
My question is: [the (2,2,1) boundedness of a “product” operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191551/the-2-2-1-boundedness-of-a-product-operator).

It is in general hard to tell which website will be more useful for a particular question.

Comment: If you do, be sure to leave a link at each site to the question at the other site.

Comment: You might have a look at older discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting]. For example, [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting) or [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo).

Comment: My personal suggestion: Migrate, don't cross-post.  Since the question is [younger than 90 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/201314), you can flag it on MO and have it *moved* here, rather than having a copy on both sites.